# Segmentation fault when modifying struct in C

Tags: c, struct

I'm developing a client/server chat using C for a University project.

Everything is going fine, but i cannot fix this problem.

I created a struct to store the sockets of the two clients who have to communicate:

```
typedef struct pairing_Clients{
  int client1fd;
  int client2fd;
} pairedClients;
```

When i use it in a function that manages the communication between two clients, it gives me segfault. I tried with the following lines:

- Declared it as a global variable:

```
pairedClients *clients;
```

- Then, doing this gives me the segfault:

```
void client_handler(void *p_client) {

  pairedClients *clients = (pairedClients *)malloc(sizeof(pairedClients));
  clients->client1fd = 15;
}
```

It seems strange to me. I don't see any big problem. Any help?

Comment: You don't have to cast the return value of `malloc()` in C

Comment: can you run valgrind?

Comment: I already tried valgrind, but i don't know why, when i do it, it uses another port, so i cannot run my client on that server

Comment: "this gives me the segfault:" You mean, when you run it in a debugger you get that line in that function shown as location for that error? These 2 lines look fine except for missing `NULL` check. If you inspect the variables, does `clients` contain a valid address?

Comment: I tried putting some prints before and after, and i saw that it never prints the one after this instruction. I know this is the worst way of debugging, but i have this problem using valgrind that makes impossible for me to us e it

Comment: You don't need Valgrind to run your program in a debugger.

Comment: What happens if you add a `NULL` check?

Comment: I checked after the malloc if clients is null, and it is not. How can i debug it? I always use valgrind, i write code on atom.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247564/discussion-between-gerhardh-and-fst).

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem (including any necessary inputs, but preferably not needing any), then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 3):

When allocating you are creating a new variable and global `clients` left uninitialized. Since the context is not clear, I guess that `clients->client1fd = 15;` line is not in the same scope with the allocation line.

Just change the `malloc` line to:

```
clients = (pairedClients *)malloc(sizeof(pairedClients));
```

Also you should check the return value of `malloc`.

Comment: The two lines that gives me segfault are inside a function. However, i tried what you said, but unfortunately it still gives me segfault. Very strange.

Comment: Ok but don't forget that you are not initializing the global `clients` with that `malloc` line.

Comment: I get it now. I wanted to allocate it with malloc because i need that variable even in other functions. Is it better if i instantiate it with malloc when i declare it? Or in main?

Comment: You can't do it on the global scope in C I think so do it in the main. But in C++ you can.

Comment: If the 2 lines really are the location of the segfault, then it does not matter whether the gloval variable is initialized or not.